# bootstrap dropdown list button doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a website and testing it on my iPhone for mobile view.  still on `bootstrap 3`. It having some issue. when tap on the nav button on my iPhone nothing happened no dropdown list. and when on desktop it work with mouse click. on top of that I use JS to load this page to the index.jsp. Thanks.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("testing");
        $('#header').load('jsp/Header.jsp');

        $('#footer').load('jsp/Footer.jsp');});
```

```html
   
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>nav</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="col-sm-2" id="nav">
            <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">&#9776; 
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown">
                    <li>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 align-top " id="home">
                            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/displayHomePage"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 align-top " id="home">
                            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/displayAboutUsPage"> About Us</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li> <div class="col-sm-2 align-top " id="news">
                            <a  href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/displayNewsFeedPage">News</a>
                        </div></li>
                    <li><div class="col-sm-2 align-top " id="blog">
                            <a  href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/displayNewPostPage">Posts</a>
                        </div></li>
                        <li>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 align-top " id="home">
                            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/displayRegistrationForm">sign up</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li> <div class="col-sm-2 align-top " id="log-in">
                            <a  href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">Sign In</a>
                        </div></a></li>
                   
                </ul>
            </sec:authorize>
        </div>

       <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
       <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/Home.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/page2">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/page3">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/signup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
          </sec:authorize>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use your `js` and `jQuery` in the head section like that:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>nav</title>
  <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/Home.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-sm-2" id="nav">
    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">&#9776; 
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown">
        <li>
          <div class="col-sm-2 align-top " id="home">
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/displayHomePage"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="col-sm-2 align-top " id="home">
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/displayAboutUsPage"> About Us</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="col-sm-2 align-top " id="news">
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/displayNewsFeedPage">News</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="col-sm-2 align-top " id="blog">
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/displayNewPostPage">Posts</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="col-sm-2 align-top " id="home">
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/displayRegistrationForm">sign up</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="col-sm-2 align-top " id="log-in">
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">Sign In</a>
          </div>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </sec:authorize>
  </div>
```

Because I have faced the same problem many times so hope it works.

Comment: have try re arrange the above code like shown it still not working on the mobile.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. i figured it out i was using an <a> tag with class="drop-drop"  instead of button with <button> with class="drop-down".